# Is there a tool like SwaggerHub to manage CustomResourceDefinition (CRD) from the Kubernetes world?

Tags: kubernetes, swagger, openapi, kubernetes-custom-resources

We manage multiple CRDs just like REST APIs within out ecosystem. SwaggerHub is a great tool to centrally manage, version, lint the swagger files. Unable to find an equivalent tool for CRDs given that there's a standard OpenAPI format for CRDs as well.

Smartbear(SwaggerHub's parent company) doesn't seem to be support the same today and isn't on its roadmap either.

Any suggestions?